# std::queue.push() takes more time as the queue grows

Tags: c++, stl, queue

What I've observed is, std::queue `.push` takes longer as the queue size goes on increasing. Is it normal behavior or I am doing wrong something?

I want the time to be consistent regardless of number of elements the container has. What are better alternatives to std::queue?

Comment: Default container? It should be constant: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/push_back/

Comment: What specialization of std::queue do you use?

Comment: Maybe relevant: [discussion of complexity of deque::push_back](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8335430/complexity-requirements-for-stddequepush-back-front)

Comment: You could use `list` to guarantee O(1) push, although this may be worse than deque in real performance time and memory usage

Comment: Thanks! I guess I need to revisit the code. I use `push` at multiple places and within thread sync locks. So suspected `push` operation. But now I feel problem is somewhere else.