# Will copy constructor of an object be called upon resize of a vector

Tags: c++, vector, deque

Suppose I have a `std::vector<foo>` now I understand that insertion at the end of a vector is amortized constant. Which means it could either be O(1) or O(n) (since it acquire a new memory block , copies the old content into the new memory block). My question is when the items are copied to a newer memory block (supposedly larger) is the copy constructor of the object called again ? (The first time the copy constructor gets called is with a push_back)  , in my case will the copy constructor of foo be called again upon resize of a vector ? I know with a std::deque the copy constructor wont be called since it stores the addresses of the objects on a heap and maintains them in a vector type data structure. will the behavior be same in C++98 and C++11

Comment: The elements will be copied or move copied. This can be easily checked with a verbose type. BTW your interpretation of how `deque` works is off.

Comment: could you also expand on the deque part with an overview ? I am pretty sure copy constructors wont be called again in case of a deque. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8627373/what-data-structure-exactly-are-deques-in-c

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6292332/what-really-is-a-deque-in-stl

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the most part, yes, copy constructors will be called.

As of C++11 std::vector will try to *move* objects when reallocating.  If your object has a move constructor that will be called instead of the copy constructor.

Thanks to Piotr I now know that `std::vector` uses `std::move_if_noexcept` to determine if the move constructor can be called without throwing an exception.  See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move_if_noexcept for more information.

Comment: *"If your object has a move constructor that will be called instead of the copy constructor."*, consider mentioning `std::move_if_noexcept`

Comment: so incase of C++98 is the destructor of the old object called after its copied to new location ? and also does the pointer of the old location become invalid ?

Comment: Yes, old objects are destroyed after they are copied to the new buffer.