# Do vector objects go out of scope when assigned to a class variable?

Tags: c++, stdvector

I'm confused about how scoping and memory persistence works with std::vectors. Consider the following:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector> 

class Entity
{
     std::string name;
}

class MyClass
{
    std::vector<Entity> class_vec;
    MyClass()
    {
        std::vector<Entity> local_vec(100);
        class_vec = local_vec;
    }
}

int main(argc, char* argv[])
{
     MyClass myclass;
}
```

If the vector elements are copy by value everything should be OK but if they use move for example, bad things can happen as local_vec will go out of scope. From what I understand local_vec is created on the stack and when the constructor is exited should be removed from it.

In the documentation it says "move is used when assigning vectors when possible" - isn't this asking for problems? When do I need to be worried about a vector assigned to another vector will have its elements go out of scope if they have been created in a certain scope?

A for sure way to cause a problem is if a vector of pointers are used to reference stack objects but that isn't being done here.

Comment: `std::vector<Entity> local_vec(100); class_vec = local_vec;` -- There is nothing wrong with this code, and nothing for you to worry about.  My crystal ball is telling me you are using other languages, such as Java, Python, etc. to figure out C++.  Don't do that -- that line of code works exactly as written.

Comment: _In the documentation it says "move is used when assigning vectors when possible"_ What documentation, where? Context please.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136883/will-copy-constructor-of-an-object-be-called-upon-resize-of-a-vector

Comment: `struct foo { int i; foo() { int x = 10; i = x; }};` -- do you question whether the member variable `i` will have a correct value of `10` after the `foo` constructor is run, just because `x` has gone out-of-scope?  Of course not -- unlike other languages that have reference-semantics, C++ has value-semantics when it comes to copy and assignment.

Comment: Your link is talking about a totally different situation. It has no relevance to the code you posted. The link is about the internal implementation/operation of std::vector when an element is added to the vector and the vector's currently allocated memory is insufficient to accommodate the new element. As others have said, your posted code is fine. Also no move is involved in the posted code.

Comment: I think the key is that a vector is a vector of objects and not pointers, which for some reason I keep thinking about. If it was a vector of pointers which pointed to an object created in the constructor scope there would be a problem.

Comment: Indeed a vector allocates (or reallocates when it grows ) a  contiguous part in memory in wich the objects will be located. If it grows it moves the objects to the new places in memory and deletes the old memory. For "simple" object move means a copy for more complex types that allocate memory the will keep the allocated memory where it is but transfers ownership to the new instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If the vector elements are copy by value everything should be OK but if they use move for example, bad things can happen as local_vec will go out of scope. From what I understand local_vec is created on the stack and when the constructor is exited should be removed from it.

That's not correct. There would be no problem with move semantics in this situation. That being said, the compiler would not be permitted to apply them, so we get a copy.

```
std::vector<Entity> local_vec(100);
class_vec = local_vec;
```

We have two named vectors: `class_vec` and `local_vec`. Both are lvalue references, so we get the [copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D).

```
constexpr vector& operator=( const vector& other );
```

So, at least at a glance, C++ must call the copy assignment operator. Now, aggressive optimization and inlining *might* help with that, but it can't simply decide it wants to call a different overload.

That being said, we can force move semantics here with `std::move`, which turns an lvalue reference into an rvalue reference, communicating to the compiler that we don't plan to use the value after this fact.

```
class_vec = std::move(local_vec);
```

*Now* we've got a move assignment operator. And this still isn't a problem. In fact, it's probably an improvement. If we assume `std::vector` is defined something like this

```
// Gross oversimplification
template <typename T>
class vector {
  T* array;
  int size;
};
```

Then the move assignment operator would look something like this.

```
// Again, gross oversimplification
template <typename T>
vector<T> vector<T>::operator=(vector<T>&& that) {
  this->array = that.array;
  this->size = that.size;
  that.array = std::nullptr;
  that.size = 0;
}
```

That is, when we're done, `this` points to all of our data and `that` points to nothing. It's left in a *valid but unspecified state* (in this example, pointing to `nullptr`), so that it can be safely destructed without damaging anything else, and certainly without damaging the original data.